# Render template and insert data into local storage

Tags: python, django, json

I have a following django code where I return entries queryset:

```
def search(request):
    entries_list = Entry.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        key = request.GET.get('key', False)
        entries_list = entries_list.filter(key__icontains=key)

    return render(request, 'search.html', {
         'entries': entries_list
    })
```

What I would like to do is to print entries (key-value pairs) in my template and to store them in the local storage. How can I do this? I have tried to return JSON or to serialize it but I were not succeded.

Namely, in my javascript (for loop) code I would like to insert my queryset results, instead of some numbers:

```
{% extends  'base.html' %}

{% block head %}

<script>
var prefix = "localStorage-";
function myFunction() {
    alert("Page is loaded");
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var key = i// $("#key").attr('value');
        var value = 2*i//$("#value").attr('value');
        localStorage.setItem(prefix + key, value);      //******* setItem()
        //localStorage[prefix+key] = value; also works
    }
}

</script>


 {% endblock %}

{% block body %} onload="myFunction()"  {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{% for e in entries %}
    <h3>
        <a href="{% url 'article' e.id %}">{{ e.key }}</a>
    </h3>
    {{ e.value|safe }}
    <hr>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to generate javascript in a Django template?

```
...
function myFunction()
{
    {% for value in entries %}
        localStorage.setItem(localStorage-{{ forloop.counter0 }}, {{ value }});
    {% endfor %}
}
....
```

This will yield something like

```
....
function myFunction()
{
    localStorage.setItem(localStorage-0, 'string_version_of_entry_0');
    localStorage.setItem(localStorage-1, 'string_version_of_entry_1');
    localStorage.setItem(localStorage-2, 'string_version_of_entry_2');
    ...
}
....
```

Note that each `Entry` will be converted to a string. You can't just transfer Django objects to javascript obviously. How it is converted can be controlled by adding a `def __unicode__(self)` to `Entry`.